# Windows Azure Android

Tags: windows, azure, android, java

Помогите помять, что я делаю. Пишу мобильное приложение под андроид. На Азуре есть мобильные службы и виртуальные машины. Что такое мобильная служба? И зачем она нужна. Задача у меня стоит такая есть приложение, оно должно получать данные из базы данных, лежащей на сервере, на сервере должны произовдиться независимые вычисления, включая работу с базой данных. Дак что мне необходимо использовать? Я считал, что мне нужен именно сервер, который будет рабоатть с базой данных и пересылать данные на приложение. Но зачем тогда Мобильная служба? Пhошу помощи!

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе как раз подойдут Azure Mobile Services. 
Azure Mobile Services позволяют тебе закачать в Azure твоё серверное приложение и при помощи него даже посылать Push Notifications. 
Как правило такой сервис и есть ни что иное как обычный Webservice с базой данных. Я не знаю,  как в яве или еще где, но в .NET для этого рекомендуют использовать т.н. Web API.

А в чём же преимущества, спросишь ты. А вот в чём: Azure Mobile Services имеют 99.95% SLA (Service Layer Agreement - аля стабильность) и при этом стоят по сути сущие копейки. На сегодняшний день до 500 тысяч запросов на такой сервер обойдутся тебе, вроде, в 0.0 рублей. Ну и дальнейшие запросы тоже по весьма гуманной цене.

Ежели ты решишь сделать тоже самое в Azure но при помощи Cloud Servcies то тебе это обойдется минимум в 50€ в месяц. Вот такая вот математика...